# How to integrate Emacs + Lab + Magit

Tags: magit

I'd like to use [lab](https://github.com/zaquestion/lab) hub wrapper for handling mr/issues of my own custom gitlab server. When I open a pull-request using hub (github) it's works fine the git-commit-mode from [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit), syntax highlight  working and C-c C-c / C-c C-k keybindings for commit/abort.

However for lab doens't works. Seems that I need setup something in my config to the MERGE_EDITMSG buffer can work. After opening a mr https://i.stack.imgur.com/vARyL.png using `lab mr create`. I cannot abort easily and there is no syntax highlight too.  To complete the commit it's necessary just C-x C-c, it's ok, but would be better to be consistent with the rest o [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) stuff.

Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/b2kfrw/support_emacs_magit_lab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in earlier versions of this answer (use the history feature if you are into that sort of thing) the value of `git-commit-filename-regexp` had to be adjusted to also match `MERGEREQ_EDITMSG`.

I have done that now, update `git-commit` to get the new regexp.

Comment: That is the name: https://imgur.com/L4W0tnx.png `MERGEREQ_EDITMSG`